# Folland's real analysis, proposition 5.5

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

On page 157, proposition 5.5 states

> Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. If $u$ is a real linear functional on $\mathcal{X}$ and $f: \mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{C}$ is defined by $f(x)=u(x)-iu(ix)$, then $f$ is complex linear. If $\mathcal{X}$ is normed, we have $\|u\|=\|f\|$.

I fail to understand why the book's proof is sufficient so I make my attempt, which failed when $f$ takes in a complex value:

> The book's proof:
>
> If $u$ is real linear and $f(x) = u(x) - iu(ix)$, then $f$ is clearly linear over $\mathbb{R}$. And $f(ix) = u(ix) - iu(-x) = u(ix) + iu(x) = if(x)$, so $f$ is also linear over $\mathbb{C}$.

> My attempt:
>
> Assume $x,y\in\mathcal{R}$.
> $f(ax)=u(ax)-iu(ix)$ and
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> f(x+y) &= u(x+y) - iu(i(x+y))\\
> &=u(x+y)-i(x+y)u(i)\\
> &=u(x) + u(y) - iu(ix) - iu(iy)\\
> &=f(x)+f(y)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> so $f$ is linear over $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> $f(x+iy) = u(x+iy) - iu(ix-y) = ?$

May I ask how to proceed in my attempt? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't evaluate $f$ on $x+iy$, if $x,y$ are real. You evaluate $f$ on elements of $\chi$. If you want to prove that $f$ is linear, the full condition, from the beginning, then you take $x,y\in \chi$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$. Then you evaluate $f(ax+by)$. You probably have to break $a$ and $b$ into its real and imaginary parts anyway.

Comment: @NDB Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: Additivity of $f$ is obvious. Concerning homogeneity it suffices that $f$ is homogeneous with respect to real coefficients and $f(ix)=if(x).$ The first property you get for free as $u$ is linear with respect to real coefficients. The second property follows from the particular definition of $f.$